# How do I get my async function to work? Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, asynchronous, async-await, discord.js

I'm working on a discord bot and need to check if a user is in my database or not so that I can make a profile for new users.
I'm new at using async functions so I've been looking around for examples but can't seem to get it to work how I want.

Using Typescript / DiscordJS / mongoDB

```
let profileData;
try {
  const makeProfile = async () => {
    profileData = await profileModels.findOne({ userID: message.author.id });
    if (!profileData) {
      setTimeout(async () => {
        await new profileSchema({
          userID: message.author.id,
          serverID: message.guild?.id,
          balance: 0,
          inventory: [],
          bank: 0,
        }).save();
      }, 1000);
    }
  };
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err);
}
```

Comment: Uh, you're never calling `makeProfile`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
async function makeProfile() {
  try {
    const profileData = await profileModels.findOne({
      userID: message.author.id,
    });

    await new profileSchema({
      userID: message.author.id,
      serverID: message.guild?.id,
      balance: 0,
      inventory: [],
      bank: 0,
    }).save();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks so much! worked perfectly

Comment: This is missing the 1s delay though

Answer (score -1):

```js
let profileData; // Left this in global scope in case you want to access it outside the function scope
async function makeProfile() {
  try {
    profileData = await profileModels.findOne({ userID: message.author.id });
    if (!profileData) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        await new profileSchema({
          userID: message.author.id,
          serverID: message.guild?.id,
          balance: 0,
          inventory: [],
          bank: 0,
        }).save();
      }, 1000);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err); // Would recommend console.error for errors
  }
}
```

Make sure to `await` the function when calling it if you care about the timing.

---

Since this is a discord bot and the function appears to be initialized inside the message_create listener, you might want to consider making a parameter for `message` and moving this out of the event listener.